# What to do if a large images fails to display on a GUI?

Tags: java, user-interface

This is a java snippet, but I guess that this question is pertinent to other languages...

```
  public BufferedImage getVisualisation(){
    try {
        BufferedImage visualisation = ImageIO.read(from some inputStream);
        return visualisation;
    } catch (IOException e) {
      // What do I do here?
    }
}
```

The code reads some data from somewhere and tries to generate a BufferedImage.  This image is to be displayed, on say a JPanel.  Let’s now assume that the IO process throws a wobble, fails and an IOException is thrown and immediately caught by the catch block.

Do I then just throw another exception?  Do I return a null?  Consider that there will be code expecting a proper image to display on the GUI.  It’s not like a numeric calculation going wrong and returning 0 or null.  There’s potentially a large part of the GUI that will not be painted.  Would you create another BufferedImage of a broken window pane or something so that it can be displayed to inform the user that there is a problem?  Or do you leave it unpainted and pop up a warning dialogue?  Or you just return null and deal with it further down stream?

What is best practice in these cases to create the best experience for the user?

Comment: If you can't handle the exception, don't catch it in the first place. Let the exception bubble up the stack to a place where you *can* deal with it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to log the problem somewhere so a developer or tech support person can debug it. That means formatting and printing the stack trace to a log file.

As to the image, I'd keep a separate "Image cannot be loaded" icon to substitute in place of the failed image. The possibilities are endless... you could have the image display the stack trace and error message when clicked, display an error on the image itself (with a little coding work), or whatever works in your application to inform the user that something unexpected happened.